# Как отключить iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Допустим на странице несколько iframe-ов, надо по нажатию кнопки их отключить.
Подскажите у кого время есть.

Comment: что значит "отключить iframe"?

Comment: может удалить?..